# How to make images revert the opacity affect when hovered?

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity

For example, when I hover over an image that I've set an opacity on, I'd like the images to be nontransparent as it is initially.

Got it resolved now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `:hover` pseudoselector.

```css
img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

img:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/1c/74/6c/1c746c3dffb830b890a21e5bb1ef7500.jpg" height="200" width="200"
```

Comment: Ah of course. Makes soo much sense now. Thank you, @RichardHamilton!